# How to draw pin annotation on current location, MapKit, Swift, iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, annotations

I have a MapView on a storyboard with the `User Location` option checked. I've also written some code to draw another annotation onto the map. The coordinates for this annotation (`tappedCoordinates`) are derived from a registered gesture.

```
//add new annotation
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = tappedCoordinates
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

//add circle radius
let circle = MKCircle(center: tappedCoordinates, radius: 20)
mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: tappedCoordinates, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.002, longitudeDelta: 0.002)), animated: true)
mapView.add(circle)
```

This code allows the user to draw an annotation (a pin) onto the map. It works fine, except when the user attempts to draw the annotation on their current location. Instead the `MapView` thinks your selecting the Current Location annotation, and displays "Current Location", instead of allowing the user to draw the custom annotation.

How do I stop the user location annotation from being tappable, and allow my custom annotation to be dropped in the same area? I do not want to remove the current location annotation.

Comment: You may probably set userInteractionEnabled to false to prevent touch on it

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set map view delegate with controller
    self.mapView.delegate = self
}
}
```

Override its delegate methods:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
    return nil
}

if (annotation.isKindOfClass(CustomAnnotation)) {
    let customAnnotation = annotation as? CustomAnnotation
    mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("CustomAnnotation") as MKAnnotationView!

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = customAnnotation?.annotationView()
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    self.addBounceAnimationToView(annotationView)
    return annotationView
} else {
    return nil
}
}
```

//Add pin (MKPointAnnotation)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Set map view delegate with controller
self.mapView.delegate = self

let newYorkLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.730872, -74.003066)
// Drop a pin
let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
dropPin.coordinate = newYorkLocation
dropPin.title = "USA"
mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locObject = locations.last
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    let centerCoordinate = locObject?.coordinate
    annotation.coordinate = centerCoordinate!
    annotation.title = "Title"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

}